# total of entries where record/row count equals 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an entries table: id, name

Users can enter as many times as they want.

I want to retrieve the total of users who have entered 2 times.

So if the table looked like this:

```
user_id   name
-------   ----
3         chuck
4         larry
5         george
3         chuck
4         larry
```

The query would return 2, since user_id 3 and 4 were the only user's who had two entries into the entries table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select user_id , count(name) as c from table_name GROUP BY user_id having count(*) = 2
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab3de/7)

Answer (score 1):

use `count(*)` method

```
select userid,count(*) as count 
from (select count(*) as c,userid 
      from entries 
      here c>=2 group by user_id) 
as dummy_table
```

Comment: you can not use "C" in the same query:  check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ab3de/8

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
(
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING count = 2
)
```